# can you be hacked from commented out html form?

Tags: security

If I have an html form commented out using `<!-- form -->`

Which has some input fields that are not sanitized, can someone use those to do bad queries to the db? For example with firebug, can someone remove `<!--` and use those input fields to do something nasty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the script handling the form, a person can certainly create a local copy of that form without the comments.  Indeed, if they know what the input names and semantics are, they can create their own form altogether.  There's no good way of detecting whether or not a form submission is from your form or something else masquerading as it.

Answer (score 1):

All the info you send to the user can be modified by him, so if you don't want him to see that info, don't comment it out, just remove it or comment out with php.

And if your database is able to receive 'bad' queries is that something is wrong coded, because an user can post his own data even if you don't send him any form to do so. You have to add server sided security (Authentication, checking user rights, sql injection...) even if your HTML don't allows it, because server side code can't be modified by user.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but I'd check it this way: edit the HTML from the browser's element inspector and uncomment it. If then you can use it, you can be hacked.